# JavaFX ControlsFX Autocomplete: How to get popup result into a new ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, javafx-8, controlsfx

I've created a Text Field and bind it into a AutoCompletion.

```
AutoCompletionBinding acb = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(new TextField(), FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apple", "Orange", "Wood Apple", "Avacado"));
```

When I type 'App' in textfield. The List is Showing below result.

```
Apple
Wood Apple
```

What I want is get this result into a new `ObservableList`.

Comment: You're just creating a TextField, which you cannot access. You have to get the value from the field. For example TextField tf = new TextField(); tf.getText();

Comment: ahhh, my bad. I just mentioned above. don't think about that. my working code is way bit differ than that. what I want is retrieving popup result into new observableList. that's all

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to retrieve the word, choosen by AutoCompletion:

```
TextField testTextField = new TextField();
AutoCompletionBinding<String> acb = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(testTextField , FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apple", "Orange", "Wood Apple", "Avacado"));
acb.setOnAutoCompleted(new EventHandler<AutoCompletionBinding.AutoCompletionEvent<String>>()
{

  @Override
  public void handle(AutoCompletionEvent<String> event)
  {
    String valueFromAutoCompletion = event.getCompletion();
  }
});
```

Comment: this is returning auto completed result. which selected by user. my requirement is for get list down result into new observable arraylist. which I mentioned above.